# Next/previous question button?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, design, user-interface

Often I go over the list of active question on a site one by one. 
The way I do so right now is by going back to the main page and 
then opening the next question.

I think it would be useful to have buttons linking on the question page linking to the next/previous active questions.

Does this sound like a good idea?

Comment: Could you clarify how you'd define what is the "next" question after a given question? If you mean on front page, that's the last modified date, and it can change while you are viewing a question.

Comment: @tepples, I think it would be fine if the next question links to the question that was the latest edited one before the current question _at the time the question is open_. While I read the question the next question may get edited and move to the top. There may be a few question that I would miss because they got edited while I was reading the question and they have moved above it. But this also happens with in the currently: when I go back to the main page some questions might have moved to the top. I normally do a second go from top after I finish to make sure I also checked them.

Comment: Seems to be implemented: [New next/previous question button introduced -- how does it work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294458)

Comment: It only seems to be implemented in test. I would personally welcome such buttons (maybe not as they have been implemented as seen [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294458), as obtrusive buttons to the side, but as a pair of arrows next to the question title maybe), as having to return to the newest questions list is quite unproductive (requiring an extra click) and infuriating.

Answer (score 3):

I think this would be useful in a minority of cases. That's certainly not to say it's a bad idea, I'm just not sure how often someone would benefit from it.

The fact of the matter is, "next" and "previous" as design elements are generally better-suited for things that actually have order. Yes, of course, you can sort questions by all sorts of things, but none really hold any meaning. The fact that one question was asked earlier or later than another question, if they were sorted chronologically, wouldn't have any impact on your ability to answer those questions.

For that very reason, the front page is somewhat randomized (with restrictions) to highlight interesting and unanswered questions. Indicating that there's any predetermined or large-scale reproducible order there is consequently invalid. Thus, next and previous buttons would be misleading. They make more sense on things that do have strict and logical ordering (contacts ordered alphabetically, pages on a calendar, etc.). Their function would be a bit too arbitrary to be useful.

Beyond that, I think they could have some unintended consequences. Most notably, I'd worry that users would get a bit, shall we say, "caught up in the moment." We see it on reviews as it is, and I'd hate to see it on answers, where a person will start just clicking through "next," "next," "next," and making judgments without fully understanding what's going on. I honestly have no idea whether this would be relevant or not, but I can imagine someone answering questions in a similar fashion, just trying to get rep points up without contributing everything. If we continue to have it being strict actions of "I'm reading this question title and I'm clicking on this question," I think people are probably going to be a bit more engaged with each one.

Finally, I think something like this would be tiring pretty quickly. I choose against clicking into...I'd be comfortable to say "a significant majority" of the questions I see, either because they don't interest me or because I have absolutely no knowledge in the area they're addressing. Not to mention, there are just so many. I wouldn't want to be forced into looking at every single one. And yes, I know you clearly aren't suggesting we be forced into use of these buttons, but every design decision has to be made on the premise that it will be useful, and I'm just not sure of the half-life of a feature like this, before people grow bored of it.

Again, I'm not saying whether it would be a good idea or a bad one, these are just my concerns.

Comment: Thanks. I think the first issue also applies to email conversations (e.g. in GMail) and despite this I find the next/previous email shortcut is still quite useful. The second, I am not sure I understand it. There is no reputation for clicking on next and there is no reason to comment for reputation because of a next button. The third issue is more serious. On smaller sites it is actually possible to read _every_ question, definitely not so on larger sites like [SO] or [Math.SE].

Comment: @Kaveh Yeah, I mean again, I'm certainly not trying to say it's not a good idea, I'm just saying these are things to be aware of. As for the first one and your relation to email clients, that's a good point, but I also think it's a very different landscape trying to read through questions on those bigger sites. People (tend to) read every email they receive, but there's no way anyone will read every question on SO. I meant that people will start answering even if they aren't equipped to, if they're encouraged to look at every single question. If that makes any sense.